# Insert into Table SQLDev

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to insert into a table. I am new to this and trying to learn.I am using SQLDEV. I believe it has to be some time of nested loop but I just can't figure it out. The table is for employees and their dependents. I am just trying to set the SEQ_NO. For example every person with a BREL_CODE of 'E' SEQ_NO should be set to 1. After that the numbers should go increment by 1 until it reaches a new PIDM  then the loop should start over again and repeat the process. For example.... the first 9 rows in the SEQ_NO columns should be 1,2,3,4,2,1,2,1,1 ...

```
Sample Data:
(PZRBENE_PIDM,PZRBENE_SEQ_NO,PZRBENE_BENE_PIDM,PZRBENE_BENE_LAST_NAME,PZRBENE_BENE_FIRST_NAME,PZRBENE_BENE_MI,PZRBENE_BREL_CODE,PZRBENE_SEX_IND,PZRBENE_BIRTH_DATE,PZRBENE_SSN,PZRBENE_MEMBER_TYPE,PZRBENE_DEL_IND) values (33159,null,null,'Regr','Ken',null,'E','F',to_date('09-FEB-68','DD-MON-RR'),'111111111','N','N');
Insert into PZRBENE (PZRBENE_PIDM,PZRBENE_SEQ_NO,PZRBENE_BENE_PIDM,PZRBENE_BENE_LAST_NAME,PZRBENE_BENE_FIRST_NAME,PZRBENE_BENE_MI,PZRBENE_BREL_CODE,PZRBENE_SEX_IND,PZRBENE_BIRTH_DATE,PZRBENE_SSN,PZRBENE_MEMBER_TYPE,PZRBENE_DEL_IND) values (33159,null,null,'Reg','Den',null,'H','M',to_date('24-DEC-71','DD-MON-RR'),'222222222','D','N');
Insert into PZRBENE (PZRBENE_PIDM,PZRBENE_SEQ_NO,PZRBENE_BENE_PIDM,PZRBENE_BENE_LAST_NAME,PZRBENE_BENE_FIRST_NAME,PZRBENE_BENE_MI,PZRBENE_BREL_CODE,PZRBENE_SEX_IND,PZRBENE_BIRTH_DATE,PZRBENE_SSN,PZRBENE_MEMBER_TYPE,PZRBENE_DEL_IND) values (33159,null,null,'Regr','Lev',null,'C','M',to_date('12-NOV-10','DD-MON-RR'),'333333333','D','N');
Insert into PZRBENE (PZRBENE_PIDM,PZRBENE_SEQ_NO,PZRBENE_BENE_PIDM,PZRBENE_BENE_LAST_NAME,PZRBENE_BENE_FIRST_NAME,PZRBENE_BENE_MI,PZRBENE_BREL_CODE,PZRBENE_SEX_IND,PZRBENE_BIRTH_DATE,PZRBENE_SSN,PZRBENE_MEMBER_TYPE,PZRBENE_DEL_IND) values (33159,null,null,'Reger','Ja',null,'C','M',to_date('12-AUG-05','DD-MON-RR'),'444444444','D','N');
Insert into PZRBENE (PZRBENE_PIDM,PZRBENE_SEQ_NO,PZRBENE_BENE_PIDM,PZRBENE_BENE_LAST_NAME,PZRBENE_BENE_FIRST_NAME,PZRBENE_BENE_MI,PZRBENE_BREL_CODE,PZRBENE_SEX_IND,PZRBENE_BIRTH_DATE,PZRBENE_SSN,PZRBENE_MEMBER_TYPE,PZRBENE_DEL_IND) values (33161,null,null,'Lace','Hary','C','H','M',to_date('15-SEP-47','DD-MON-RR'),'555555555','D','N');
Insert into PZRBENE (PZRBENE_PIDM,PZRBENE_SEQ_NO,PZRBENE_BENE_PIDM,PZRBENE_BENE_LAST_NAME,PZRBENE_BENE_FIRST_NAME,PZRBENE_BENE_MI,PZRBENE_BREL_CODE,PZRBENE_SEX_IND,PZRBENE_BIRTH_DATE,PZRBENE_SSN,PZRBENE_MEMBER_TYPE,PZRBENE_DEL_IND) values (33161,null,null,'Love','Rose','M','E','F',to_date('10-FEB-51','DD-MON-RR'),'666666666','N','N');
Insert into PZRBENE (PZRBENE_PIDM,PZRBENE_SEQ_NO,PZRBENE_BENE_PIDM,PZRBENE_BENE_LAST_NAME,PZRBENE_BENE_FIRST_NAME,PZRBENE_BENE_MI,PZRBENE_BREL_CODE,PZRBENE_SEX_IND,PZRBENE_BIRTH_DATE,PZRBENE_SSN,PZRBENE_MEMBER_TYPE,PZRBENE_DEL_IND) values (33163,null,null,'Wilon','La','E','C','F',to_date('12-FEB-02','DD-MON-RR'),'777777777','D','N');
Insert into PZRBENE (PZRBENE_PIDM,PZRBENE_SEQ_NO,PZRBENE_BENE_PIDM,PZRBENE_BENE_LAST_NAME,PZRBENE_BENE_FIRST_NAME,PZRBENE_BENE_MI,PZRBENE_BREL_CODE,PZRBENE_SEX_IND,PZRBENE_BIRTH_DATE,PZRBENE_SSN,PZRBENE_MEMBER_TYPE,PZRBENE_DEL_IND) values (33163,null,null,'Wilson','Janet',null,'E','F',to_date('01-JAN-64','DD-MON-RR'),'888888888','N','N');
Insert into PZRBENE (PZRBENE_PIDM,PZRBENE_SEQ_NO,PZRBENE_BENE_PIDM,PZRBENE_BENE_LAST_NAME,PZRBENE_BENE_FIRST_NAME,PZRBENE_BENE_MI,PZRBENE_BREL_CODE,PZRBENE_SEX_IND,PZRBENE_BIRTH_DATE,PZRBENE_SSN,PZRBENE_MEMBER_TYPE,PZRBENE_DEL_IND) values (33164,null,null,'Choski','Jon',null,'E','M',to_date('14-MAR-52','DD-MON-RR'),'123456789','N','N');
Insert into PZRBENE (PZRBENE_PIDM,PZRBENE_SEQ_NO,PZRBENE_BENE_PIDM,PZRBENE_BENE_LAST_NAME,PZRBENE_BENE_FIRST_NAME,PZRBENE_BENE_MI,PZRBENE_BREL_CODE,PZRBENE_SEX_IND,PZRBENE_BIRTH_DATE,PZRBENE_SSN,PZRBENE_MEMBER_TYPE,PZRBENE_DEL_IND) values (33169,null,null,'Parck','Wilim','G','C','M',to_date('09-MAY-03','DD-MON-RR'),'99999999','D','N');


My Code:
update pzrbene
set pzrbene_seq_no = 1
where pzrbene_brel_code = 'E';
*/

set serveroutput on:
Declare 
cursor p_cur is 

select  pzrbene_seq_no,pzrbene_pidm
from pzrbene
where pzrbene_brel_code <> 'E'
order by pzrbene_pidm;

p_pidm      PZRBENE.PZRBENE_PIDM%TYPE;
p_seq_no     number := 0;
p_brel_code   pzrbene.pzrbene_brel_code%TYPE; 

Begin

  open p_cur; 
  fetch p_cur into p_seq_no,p_pidm ;
  while p_cur%FOUND
    LOOP
     update pzrbene 
      SET PZRBENE_SEQ_NO = p_seq_no + 1 where p_pidm = pzrbene.pzrbene_pidm and p_brel_code= pzrbene_brel_code;
  fetch p_cur into p_seq_no,p_pidm;
  end loop;

  end;
  /
```

Comment: Where's is your code?

Comment: What is it about your data that orders it? There's nothing in the sample data that you've provided that says for a given `PIDM`, which row comes first, next etc. Also, is there a primary key or some other uniqueness that can identify each individual row?

Comment: I don;t see an INSERT startement in there, why would you expect it to insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This PLSQL block worked for me. Nothing special here, just the matter of proper ordering.
I assumed, that someone with MEMBER_TYPE = 'N' is the boss.

```
declare 
  v_counter number := 0;
  cursor cur is select pzrbene_pidm pidm, pzrbene_brel_code brel_code 
    from pzrbene order by pzrbene_pidm, pzrbene_member_type desc 
    for update;
begin
  for rec in cur loop
    if rec.brel_code = 'E'  then 
      v_counter := 1; 
    else 
      v_counter := v_counter + 1; 
    end if;
    update pzrbene set pzrbene_seq_no = v_counter where current of cur;
  end loop;
end;
```

Output after execution:

```
select pzrbene_pidm pidm, pzrbene_seq_no, 
    pzrbene_bene_last_name||' '||pzrbene_bene_first_name bene_name, 
    pzrbene_brel_code brel_code, pzrbene_member_type member_type
  from pzrbene 
  order by pzrbene_pidm, pzrbene_member_type desc

  PIDM PZRBENE_SEQ_NO BENE_NAME                            BREL_CODE MEMBER_TYPE
------ -------------- ------------------------------------ --------- -----------
 33159              1 Regr Ken                             E         N           
 33159              2 Reg Den                              H         D           
 33159              3 Regr Lev                             C         D           
 33159              4 Reger Ja                             C         D           
 33161              1 Love Rose                            E         N           
 33161              2 Lace Hary                            H         D           
 33163              1 Wilson Janet                         E         N           
 33163              2 Wilon La                             C         D           
 33164              1 Choski Jon                           E         N           
 33169              2 Parck Wilim                          C         D
```

You may want to change ordering to something more complicated, for instance:

```
order by pzrbene_pidm, 
  case when pzrbene_member_type='N' then 1 else 2 end, pzrbene_bene_brel_code
```

it's up to you, I don't know the meaning of these columns, which are more important, which less, when the rest is equal between two rows.